# How to get the clicked location of an image to corrospond to the Row x Column of a graph?

Tags: image, graph, click

I have 10,000+ individual images.  I have a representation of all the images in the form of a graph.  Each colored dot on the graph corresponds to an image.

[Link to the graph.](http://oi59.tinypic.com/2vwwa4h.jpg)

What I'd like is for the user to click a dot and be taken to the corresponding image based on the dot's Row x Column location.  For example if they click a dot in the 2nd row 4th column, they'd get image (2,4).

The question then is what is an efficient way to implement this?  Making 10,000 clickable images seems like a terrible solution.  I've thought of seeing where in the image the user clicks, but I'm not sure how to accurately correspond that to the Row x Column.

Thank you in advance for your help.